# Symfony 3.3 select Box with Ajax

Tags: symfony

[SelectBox_Dynamic][1]

How can I do something like this [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp with Symfony 3?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to serve your entities through a REST API and `get/update` with Ajax

You can build our own API with the [Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) or use Bundle like [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but there is no other way easier with Ajax only since I need it as soon as possible, and to turn to API REST will be still a learning time for me, :( 
Thanks,

Comment: You can do it in 2 minutes if your under deadline, Entitymanager get your entites, make a static php array and return New jsonReponse($array)